# What's the air flow on reference fan for nVidia GeForce 9500 GT?

Tags: fan, nvidia-geforce

Does anyone know the airflow of the fan on nVidia's reference cooler for GeForce 9500 GT ([like the one here, middle of the page](http://www.fudzilla.com/reviews/item/18869-superfast-galaxy-9500-gt-card-running-at-700mhz))?

The fan died on a friend's computer and I'm thinking about replacing it. The cooler looks just like the one on the site I linked to.

I'm thinking about replacing the fan with one which has similar capabilities, but I have no idea what are capabilities of fan on 9500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you buy another 40mm fan like the one on the reference cooler, it too will be loud and will fail. So when this happens to me, I replace it with an aftermarket cooler from Zalman or Arctic Cooling.

Alternatively, you could remove the cover from the reference heat sink and zip-tie on any 80mm or 120mm fan.

Comment: I think that I'm going to use the 80mm or 120mm option.